# MPMoviePlayerViewController auto dismiss while home button pressed

Tags: ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I called doPlayMovie method to play some file on iPad, but when i press Home button try to switch my app to background, the player auto dismissed.

is there any way to keep the player always there do not dismiss?

```
-(MPMoviePlayerViewController*)moviePlayerController{
    if(!_moviePlayerController){
        _moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]init];
    }
    return _moviePlayerController;
}

-(MPMoviePlayerController*)moviePlayer{
    return self.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer;
}

-(void)doPlayMovie:(NSString *)filepath{
    self.moviePlayerController = nil;

    NSURL *playUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    self.moviePlayer.contentURL = playUrl;
    [self.moviePlayer play];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.moviePlayerController];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify UIBackgroundModes to audio in your plist file (only for iOS > 4). See [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/) to see steps for setting up app to play audio in background.